# Loop All Processes Memory

Tags: api, memory, vb6, process

How could I, using "ReadProcessMemory" API, loop through all running processes of the machine and scan for an Array of strings and return a true/false value if any one or more are contained in the memory of the process - using VB6?

Example:

```
Strings() = {"@STRING1@", "@ANOTHERSTRING@", "$TRING"}
Loop # Processes
    If InStr(ProcessMemory(#), Strings) Then
        MsgBox(Process(#) & " Contains one of the strings!")
    End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

i dont know but i used wmi in my program

something how that

```
Public Sub KillProcess(ByVal processName As String)

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Dim oWMI
Dim ret
Dim sService
Dim oWMIServices
Dim oWMIService
Dim oServices
Dim oService
Dim servicename

Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:")
Set oServices = oWMI.InstancesOf("win32_process")

For Each oService In oServices

    servicename = LCase$(Trim$(CStr(oService.Name) & ""))

    If InStr(1, servicename, LCase(processName), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        ret = oService.Terminate
    End If

Next

If Not oServices Is Nothing Then Set oServices = Nothing
If Not oWMI Is Nothing Then Set oWMI = Nothing


ErrHandler:
    Err.Clear

End Sub
```